# Is passive-aggressive behavior conscious or unconscious?

Tags: personality, consciousness, behavior

It is my experience that people who show passive aggressive behavior do not realize it or at least do not admit it.

Which leads me to the question whether passive-aggressive behavior can be controlled?
Or is passive-aggressive behavior a symptome of something else and therefore somewhat unconscious?

Comment: We work differently to most SE sites, where we have a strict policy that all questions should [show evidence of prior research](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/993). Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google? This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you still have trouble with this, please visit the [ask] page or [meta].